# Keep close button on upper right corner even when image scales

Tags: html, css

How the heck can I keep a close button on the right top corner of an image even when I scale the image using css? the scale is in terms of when the user make the browser a different size the image is scaled. 
p.s. how come when I use full_close  {left:0px;} I lose the image completely
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dmEpF/23/)

```
.fit {
 max-width: 100%;
 }

.center {
 display: block;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0;
}

.right {
 position: relative;
 right: 0;
}

#full_image {    
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
}

#full_image img {     
    left: 0px;       
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#full_image ul {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#full_image  li:first-child {
    display: list-item;
    position: absolute;
}

#full_image  li {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;

}


#full_image .full_close{
    background-color:yellow;
    top: 10px;     
    cursor: pointer;
     height: 29px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;    
    width: 29px;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0px;
}

 <div id="full_image">
 <ul><li><img class="center fit right" src="http://cdn.funkyspacemonkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/steve-wozniak-white-iphone-4.jpg"/></li></ul>
  <span> <a href="#" class="full_close "></a></span>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you've got a lot of unnecessary styles and elements. Check out the updated example, this should be all that you need: http://jsfiddle.net/dmEpF/34/

```
<div id="full_image">

    <img src="http://cdn.funkyspacemonkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/steve-wozniak-white-iphone-4.jpg"/>

    <a href="#" class="full_close">X</a>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#full_image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#full_image img {     
    max-width: 100%;
}

#full_image .full_close{
    background-color:yellow;
    top: 10px;     
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 29px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;    
    width: 29px;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 10px;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: No I didn't. The image scales just fine.

Comment: Thanks but the image scaling is gone

Comment: The image stays the same size when you make the window smaller

Comment: No it doesn't: [small window](http://i.imgur.com/ycF4dT9.png), [large window](http://i.imgur.com/GrO0ZZp.png)

Comment: Fix the CSS: #full_image img {     
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: @MarcAudet you don't need `width:100%`, images are by default full size

Comment: I am using Firefox.  I checked in Chrome, and you are right, it works.  Firefox needs the width set to 100%.

Comment: @MarcAudet - Chrome. I tried FF and see what you mean. The example has been fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/dmEpF/34/

Comment: There is more than one way of fixing it! We are all good now!